# Azure B2C account linking and the difference between alternativeSecurities and userIdentities

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been reviewing some [example custom policies that revolve around account linking](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/account-linkage-unified) which I would like to integrate in to my own set of policies. I've found the Azure B2C documentation lacking when it comes to explaining the difference between an 'alternative security' and 'user identities'.

The account linking policies I've been reviewing interact with a user's collection of identities via a handful of claims transformations (e.g. `CreateUserIdentity`, `AddItemToUserIdentityCollection`, `RemoveItemToUserIdentityCollection` and `GetIssuersFromUserIdentityCollectionTransformation`). The only place these claims transformations appear to be documented is in a random [github issue comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52874#issuecomment-617193944) posted more than two years ago. All the sample account linking policies also haven't been touched in a couple of years.

On the other hand, the base policy from the default starter packs use [documented claims transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations) to interact with a user's collection of identities (or at least to add an entry there when a user signs up via social idp). There are claims transformations documented here that match all the user identity ones above (e.g. `CreateAlternativeSecurityId`, `AddItemToAlternativeSecurityIdCollection`, `RemoveAlternativeSecurityIdByIdentityProvider` and `GetIdentityProvidersFromAlternativeSecurityIdCollectionTransformation`).

The distinction between these two concepts is really not clear to me. Why are there seemingly two ways (along with a parallel set of claims transformations), to interact with identities?

Can account linking can be achieved using the *documented* alternative security claims transformations? This would go against what appears to be the recommendation to use `userIdentities` claims transformations with account linking, but using years-old samples employing undocumented features really doesn't fill me with much confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use either.

They are essentially two different naming conventions that refer to the same base structure.

Refer [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-identities-and-linking-them-in-azure-ad-b2c-33b72fcbfd25) and [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/linking-a-federated-login-against-an-existing-azure-ad-b2c-local-account-ea2db2fc2252).

Comment: Ok, that's a really confusing move by MS....